# Mongodb user account and child records

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm new to nosql / mongodb. I have a user account with numerous child records that require the ability to be easily searched.

Example

```
Dealer account
Vehicle Listings
```

I need to be able to easily and efficiently search the vehicles, but I also need to be able to associate the listings to a user account. In my relational database I just create separate tables and join them together. What is the recommended way of doing this in nosql / mongodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Mongo, you aren't generally supposed to use it for storing data that must always be directly related to another dataset. In your example though, you could have an array within the Dealer's document contain all of the objectIDs for the corresponding listing. This would make finding them much easier.

EX:

```
DEALER:
{
  name: dealer's name
  location: dealer's location
  listings:{
    {
      carType: car type
      something else: something else....
    },
    {
      carType: car type
      something else: something else....
    }
  }
}

OR

DEALER:
{
  name: dealer's name
  location: dealer's location
  listings:{
    {
      objectID: objectID
    },
    {
      objectID: objectID
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So basically two documents one containing the vehicles and one containing the dealers and in the dealer document an array of all the vehicle documents? Is this common practice with nosql?

Comment: Kind of. Each document is similar to a row in SQL. It should be a standalone piece of information. If you are sure that the document wouldn't get too large, you could have the listings stored directly inside that array. A document in MongoDB can store nested JSON, nested BSON documents, etc.

Comment: Using your example, I'm assuming that is a single document with the embedded listings, how would I go about doing a search on say all 2016 Fords across all users?

Comment: Documents would remain very small in total, I'm just concerned with being able to search them as described in my previous post.

Comment: The second example does not lend itself to searching quite as easily. It would be fairly inefficient in that regard. The first one where the JSON objects are stored in an array would allow you to search the items within that array. You would grab the entire document and then just treat it as a standard array of JSON objects

Comment: But with the second one, wouldn't I be able to just search the vehicle documents directly?

Comment: In Mongo, you can't search any nested objects. You can only see that it is an array and the number of objects it contains. So you could access it once you had the document but you'd have to iterate through all dealers to find a specific vehicle

Comment: correct, but the only time I'd really need to do that would be if I was listing the vehicles in a user account, but in a scenario like craigslist, the vast majority of searches would be done directly against the vehicles which leads me to believe it may be best to treat these two things like a relational database? I suppose I could store some minor user info such as contact info with the vehicle doc, but might be a little bit more difficult to keep in sync with the person doc right? Sorry, coming from a relational background makes this a bit more challenging.

Comment: Well unless this is an exercise for learning, it sounds like a relational database would be the better choice in this case. At least based on the needs you have expressed so far

Comment: I'm truly exploring switching away from a relational database to a nosql database. I currently have around 600k vehicles and around 19 to 30 million photo references stored in the database. I'm using a one to many relationship with the photos and I'm finding it to really difficult to manage large updates. I was hoping to be able to store my entire vehicle record including the photo urls as single document with the photo urls embedded. I also liked how nicely Mongo appears to play with Elastic Search, so this would be my reason for considering this database.

Comment: How do others with user accounts that use a nosql database reference products back to the user bug still remain searchable?

Comment: What search queries are you thinking of running? Will you have an intermediate program able to interface with the data and format it? If you tell me what searches you need to be able to do I may be able to specify some options

Comment: year, make, model, color, transmission, geo distance, free text, etc. Very rarely do we do searches by users, generally we only need this when the user logs into their account and we need to pull back their listings.

Comment: Yes, I'm able to do whatever I need with the data. I'm using Groovy/Grails 3 as my backend.

Comment: Okay, well I would go with the second example I posted then with a slight modification. It sounds like the car is the most searched item. If that is correct, you might have to have two types of documents. The first type (documents will follow a schema) would be Owners. This would have all pertinent owner info along with the ObjectID's of all cars that person has. The second type would be a Car document. This would have all info on the Car, along with the ObjectID of the owner of that car. This would allow searching in both directions

Comment: I was thinking the samething, now I'm assuming there is no such thing as referential integrity in nosql, so I would need to be careful in managing these two items independently right? Also, would you make an attempt at storing as much info as possible in the vehicle document even if it means replication of the person document. Example, email, phone etc. ?

Comment: Unless you think you might max out the document size, I would say that it would be okay to duplicate that information. It is a trade off in data size for speed since having those things duplicated would mean less queries are used.

Comment: No chance of maxing the document size, I think it would be much quicker. Thanks for your help